# my highchart is currently is not working with pie spline chart in updating after rendering chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here is my code for updating after rendering. In this code, first three buttons `(plain, inverted and polar)` are working perfectly fine, but last 2 buttons `(pie, spline)` are not working.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
             text: 'Chart.update'
    },

    subtitle: {
             text: 'Plain'
    },

    xAxis: {
             categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            showInLegend: false
    }]

    });


    $('#plain').click(function () {
        chart.update({
                    chart: {
                    inverted: false,
                    polar: false,
                    pie:false,
                    spline:false
                    },
        subtitle: {
                    text: 'Plain'
        }
        });
    });

    $('#inverted').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
                inverted: true,
                polar: false,
                pie:false,
                spline:false
        },
        subtitle: {
                text: 'Inverted'
        }
        });
    });


    $('#polar').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
                inverted: false,
                polar: true,
                pie:false,
                spline:false
        },
        subtitle: {
                text: 'Polar'
        }
        });
    });

    $('#pie').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
                pie:true,
                inverted: false,
                polar: false,
                spline:false,
                plain:false
        },
        subtitle: {
                    text: 'Pie'
        }
        });
    });
    $('#spline').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
                type:'spline',
                inverted: false,
                polar: false,
                pie:false,
                plain:false
        },
        subtitle: {
                text: 'spline'
        }
        });
    });
```

I am studying this topic from highcahrts.com and i want to add additional chart with that.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You use chart API incorrectly. I suggest to read this part of docs http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart - on the left side you can see which options are available for chart property and what values should be set - it you want a pie, you need set chart.type to pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chart `Pie` and `spline` are of different generic chart , but column chart can be represented in two different form `plain` means default column chart, `inverted` means column chart with axis inverted and polar has XY coordinate with X axis is wrapped around the perimeter while the Y axis extends from the center to the top. They cannot be mixed to change form(plain,inverted,polar) with (pie,spline)

So to update charts to plain(column), inverted(column),polar,pie,spline I use chart `type`.Hope this will make sense.

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Chart.update'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Plain'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{

    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    showInLegend: false
  }]

});


$('#plain').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: false,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Plain'
    }
  }, true);
});

$('#inverted').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: true,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Inverted'
    }
  }, true);
});

$('#polar').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: false,
      polar: true
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Polar'
    }
  }, true);
});
$('#pie').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      inverted: false,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Pie'
    }
  }, true);
});
$('#spline').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      inverted: false,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'spline'
    }
  }, true);
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button id="plain" class="autocompare">Plain</button>
<button id="inverted" class="autocompare">Inverted</button>
<button id="polar" class="autocompare">Polar</button>
<button id="pie" class="autocompare">Pie</button>
<button id="spline" class="autocompare">Spline</button>
```

Comment: can you explain the true false that you added after subtitle .subtitle: {
      text: 'Plain'
    }
  }, true, false);

Comment: check [Chart.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update) , true is for redraw the chart after update. neglect and remove false.  If this answer solves issue then accept it as instructed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)